# Teams Webhook error: Invoke-RestMethod: Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook

Tags: powershell, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm using configured Teams webhook in my Powershell script and keep encountering the mentioned error message. What's strange, is that this exact method of configuring Webhook worked a few months ago on a different script.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
#Set URI of the Teams channel Webhook
$URI = 'https:....'

#Define Rest Method Parameters for the Teams Webhook sending
$RestMethodParameters = @{
    "URI"         = $URI
    "Method"      = 'POST'
    "Body"        = $null
    "ContentType" = 'application/json'
}

    $JSONBody = @{
    "@type"      = "MessageCard"
    "@context"   = "http://schema.org/extensions"
    "themeColor" = '0078D7'
}

#Adding text to title and body
$JSONBody += @{
        "title" = "'costReport-func' Function for connecting AzAccount has failed"
        "text"  = "Function failed at connection to AzAccount step."
    }

    #Sending the message to Teams
    ($RestMethodParameters).Body += ConvertTo-Json $JSONBody
    Invoke-RestMethod @RestMethodParameters
```

And with this I'm getting "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook." error message. What is causing the issue here?

Comment: Try skipping the explicit call to `ConvertTo-Json`, just assign `$JSONBody` directly to `$RestMethodParameters.Body`, as-is, and then let `Invoke-RestMethod` take care of serializing it

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error without ```ConvertTo-Json``` part of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Microsoft has released a preview version (2.1.0) of the Teams PowerShell module which works properly with modern authentication. It’s likely that this version will be pushed through to general availability quite quickly.
Please go through this [link](https://office365itpros.com/2021/03/10/microsoft-updates-teams-powershell-module-2-0/) for more information.